# How to remove the infinite scroll down when trying to create a virtual scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a virtual scroll in a vue project for a large table
I found one example, on the reaction, I wanted to repeat it, but I ran into a bug, when scrolling down, there is an endless scroll to the end.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-2bqji5 ?file=src%2F... - link to the code

https://codepen.io/vitkarpov/pen/OJVrQJP - this is the code on the reaction

```
    function App({ data, rowHeight, visibleRows }) {
  const rootRef = React.useRef();
  const [start, setStart] = React.useState(0);
  
  
  function getTopHeight() {
    return rowHeight * start;
  }
  function getBottomHeight() {
    return rowHeight * (data.length - (start + visibleRows + 1));
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function onScroll(e) {
      setStart(Math.min(
        data.length - visibleRows - 1,
        Math.floor(e.target.scrollTop / rowHeight)
      ));
    }
    rootRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

    return () => {
      rootRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    }
  }, [data.length, visibleRows, rowHeight]);
  
  return (
    <div style={{ height: rowHeight * visibleRows + 1, overflow: 'auto' }} ref={rootRef}>
    <div style={{ height: getTopHeight() }} />
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {data.slice(start, start + visibleRows + 1).map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <tr
            style={{ height: rowHeight }}
            key={start + rowIndex}
          >{row.map((text, colIndex) => (
            <td key={start + '' + rowIndex + colIndex}>{text}</td>
          ))}</tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style={{ height: getBottomHeight() }} />  
    </div>
  )
}

function makeTableData(w, h) {
  return new Array(h).fill(0).map((_, row) => {
    return new Array(w).fill(0).map((_, col) => {
      return row * 10 + col;
    });
  });
}

ReactDOM.render(<App
  data={makeTableData(5, 10000)}
  rowHeight={40}
  visibleRows={3}
/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As I understand it, there is just an endless drawing down, although in theory the scroll event should not work, a little stumped because of this. When scrolling up, everything is fine

Comment: You are working with React not with VueJS

Comment: I found a sample code on React. I want to apply it for Vue